# Pause for password sftp bash script file

Tags: macos, bash, authentication, sftp

I am trying to write a script to automatically upload files to a sftp server. My problem is authentication.

- I know it is not possible to store a password in a bash script for sftp.
- I can't use keys because the admin of the server won't allow me.
- I don't want to use any extras (sshpass/expect) because I can't
  guarantee they will be on the machine I'm using (the script are wanted so that the processes are not tied down to a particular machine).

Manual entry of the password is not a problem I just need to get the script to wait for the user to put the password in. At the minute when I run the script it opens terminal, prompts for the password, but when this is entered nothing else happens. If I enter the lines of code manual after it uploads everything correctly.

```
#!bin/bash/
cd /remote_directory
lcd /local_directory
put some_file.txt
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After months of looking for an answer I have finally found the solution. It was in a comment on an answer in some other thread I can't even remember. Hope this can help others out there.

Your bash script should look like this and will connect to the sftp server, prompt the user for the password, and then execute the remaining commands.

```
#!/bin/bash

sftp user@server <<!
cd /the/remote/directory
lcd /your/local/directory
put/get some.file
!
```